# Having issues making a simple script in powershell run windows media player in the background

Tags: powershell, windows-media-player

I am trying to do a simple script to where I only want a portion of my script to run in the background.  I want to run the windows media player in the background.  I am brand new to powershell and scripting in general, having a whole day and a half under my belt.  Can someone help me out and explain in basic terms how the start job works with invoke-item.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Here is my original script.  I wanted to launch a powerpoint and have my media player come up a little after I got it to load.  I realize I could do this in powerpoint, but I am using it to try and learn.  I got this to work:

```
#Call SSD
$MusicPath = "C:\powershell\Windows_Exclamation.wav"    
$Powerpoint = "C:\powershell\SSD.ppsx"     
invoke-item $Powerpoint    
start-sleep -s 3    
invoke-item $MusicPath
```

I wanted the media player to run in the background. Here is my script so far:

```
#Call SSD
$MusicPath = "C:\powershell\Windows_Exclamation.wav"    
$Powerpoint = "C:\powershell\SSD.pptx"     
invoke-item $Powerpoint    
start-sleep -s 3    
start-job -scriptblock {invoke-item} $MusicPath
```

Should I be using invoke-command or am I just lost in the sauce here?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a media.soundplayer object.

```
$MusicPath = "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav"    
Function PlayWav($path){(new-object Media.SoundPlayer "$path").play();}
PlayWav -Path "$MusicPath"
```

Comment: Why would you use the media.soundplayer object? What are the benefits of using it that way as oppossed to the way I have it written?

Comment: @mikeszokola because when i ii invoke item, it opens my media player app in the foreground.  This method runs in the background invisibly.   i.e. it's heard not seen.

Comment: I tried it exactly as written with no luck.  Does the $path need to be identified as an variable or I guess what I am trying to understand is what it is exactly saying.  I appreciate your help and I hope I sound grateful.  I am just trying to get a better understanding of it is all.  Thank you again.